# Prestashop Fax Module

Tags: php, module, prestashop, fax

I am using Prestashop for a Pizzashop. The shop owner asked me if there is any way the orders which users place online, are printed directly on fax machine? Is there any way or any module which can be useful in this regards? Or any module which can directly print orders on printer?

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

This questions boild down to:

Is there a PHP script that can send a print order to a Fax machine?

If yes, then you can solve your problem. First, you'd have to create a module for PrestaShop - specific for this shop.

This module would use `hookValidateOrder` - when an order is confirmed this hook is triggered.

In your function for this hook you would:

- Build your own document for fax (using template and variables available in the hook)
- Use buil-in functions to generate the order document - as far as I remember these functions do exists.
- Then simply post a work order to your local fax machine to print the generated PDF or your own document.

I also recommend to build Fax parameters into your module -  configurable through back-office.